# LinearRegression scores sometimes up to 13 orders of magnitude higher than supposed to

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn

Lately I've been working with real housing data, trying to predict prices. Most models work like intended and the mean RMSE is between 200.000 - 500.000, based on a 15-fold CV approach.

The weird thing is, when I try Linear Regression, in two out of fifteen folds I get a RMSE between 9.8 * 10^17 - 1.1 * 10^18, when the other 13 folds get a RMSE of about 200.000. I never had this issue, and it isn't happening with trees, rforests or Boosted Regression.

I have no idea what could be happening, never had this kind of issue. Do you have any ideas?

By the way, my code looks like this:

```
n,m=X_a_esc.shape
ones=np.ones((n,1))
X_a_esc2=np.hstack((X_a_esc, ones))
lin_reg = LinearRegression()

lin_reg.fit(X_a_esc2, Y_a)




df_predictions = lin_reg.predict(X_a_esc2) 


scores = cross_val_score(lin_reg, X_a_esc2, Y_a,     
scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=15)

rmse_scores = np.sqrt(-scores) 
display_scores(rmse_scores)
```

Where X_a_esc is feature data pre imputed and standardized. Also I'm working with around 34.000 observations and got rid of the biggest outliers: capped price at 2.000.000, but median price is 520.000 and mean price is around 730.000, so there's still lots of variation.

Tell me if you need more information. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One theory: your data matrix is ill-conditioned. Common in machine learning problems is to not care about co-linearity of columns (ex: dummy encoding categorical variables, and a baseline category is **not** dropped from the matrix). When the cross-validation is performed, you get lucky 13 out of 15 times: the matrix is conditioned fine (no colinearity). But in 2 / 15 cases, you've dropped enough rows that cause some colinearity => unstable solution => terrible predictions on the hold-out.

This normally isn't a problem in machine learning because users will use penalizers which help in fitting. In linear models, using ridge regression (`sklearn.linear_models.Ridge`) is a common way to add a penalizer.

I would suspect if you redid your program and replaced `LinearRegression` with `Ridge` with even the slightest `alpha` value, the problem would go away.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that was the issue, didn't know sklearn doesn't automatically drop a baseline category, so everything's working great now!